# Inserting handlebars in an inline style

Tags: handlebars.js, partial

So I am trying to add a partial {{> img-bg}} inside an inline style (just to keep things tidy). It works but something isn't quite right as when I try and match up the divs they don't match up.

Maybe this isn't the best way - ultimately what i want to do is have a background image and insert that image from a yml {{#each work.case-study-pk}} file along with other various bits of info.

Any ideas?

```html
{{#each work.case-study-pk}}
<div class="grid-x">

  <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 img-double-height foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
    {{> img-bg}}">
    <div class="top-left down">
      <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
      <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}

  <div class="cell small-12 medium-4">

    <div class="grid-y tile-y-bg-double-height">
      {{#each work.case-study-brixtar}}
      <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6 tile2 aligner-left foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
        {{> img-bg}}">
        <div class="align-self-bottom down tile-padding ">
          <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
          <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      {{/each}} {{#each work.case-study-memontus}}
      <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6 tile2 aligner-left foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
        {{> img-bg}}">
        <div class="align-self-bottom down tile-padding ">
          <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
          <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid-container full">

  <div class="grid-x align-center-middle text-center">

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4">
      {{#each work.case-study-umeax}}
      <div class="grid-y tile-y-bg-single-height">
        <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-12 tile4 aligner-left foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
          {{> img-bg}}">
          <div class="align-self-bottom down tile-padding">
            <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
            <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 img-single-height aligner cell-text-padder">
      <h3 class="medium p-white ">Floe is the world’s greatest design agency, apart from a few others. But the few others eat million dollar budgets for breakfast – we eat porridge!</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>



<div class="grid-x">
  {{#each work.case-study-racefox}}
  <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 img-double-height foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
    {{> img-bg}}">
    <div class="top-left down">
      <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
      <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}} {{#each work.case-study-interflora}}
  <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 img-double-height foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
    {{> img-bg}}">
    <div class="top-left down">
      <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
      <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

```html
background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

```html
case-study-pk:
  -
    img: ../assets/img/case8.jpg
    bg-img: ../assets/img/case8.jpg
    title: Personalkollen
    sub-title: Brandning and webdesign
    link: brixtar.html
    CTA: Read more

case-study-brixtar:
  -
    img: ../assets/img/brix-1.jpg
    title: Brixtar
    sub-title: Brandning app design
    link: brixtar.html
    CTA: Read more

case-study-memontus:
  -
    img: ../assets/img/case7.jpg
    title: Memontus
    sub-title: Brandning app design
    link: brixtar.html
    CTA: Read more

case-study-umeax:
  -
    img: ../assets/img/umeax-1.jpg
    title: Umeå X
    sub-title: Brandning and webdesign
    link: brixtar.html
    CTA: Read more

case-study-racefox:
  -
    img: ../assets/img/racefox-1.jpg
    title: Racefox Run
    sub-title: Brandning app design
    link: brixtar.html
    CTA: Read more

case-study-interflora:
  -
    img: ../assets/img/caseIF.jpg
    title: Interflora
    sub-title: Webdesign
    link: brixtar.html
    CTA: Read more
```

Comment: Put what you actually have in your resulting html. Your snippet is not working.

Comment: Hi Christophe - I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a design problem with your data because on your template you iterate with {{each}} on single items (that don't seems to be in an array). Maybe my example below will help you to understand what I mean.

However I managed to have an example working and I modified as few as possible your template and your data (as I said there is a confusion in data and templating). Take a look at the snippet below and feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = { 
  
  "case-study-pk": [{ 
  "img": "../assets/img/case8.jpg",
  "bg-img": "../assets/img/case8.jpg",
  "title": "Personalkollen",
  "sub-title": "Brandning and webdesign",
  "link": "brixtar.html",
  "CTA:":"Read more"}],
  
  "case-study-brixtar":[{
    "img": "../assets/img/brix-1.jpg",
    "title": "Brixtar",
    "sub-title": "Brandning app design",
    "link": "brixtar.html",
    "CTA": "Read more"}],

"case-study-memontus":[{
    "img": "../assets/img/case7.jpg",
    "title": "Memontus",
    "sub-title": "Brandning app design",
    "link": "brixtar.html",
    "CTA": "Read more"}],

"case-study-umeax":[{
    "img": "../assets/img/umeax-1.jpg",
    "title": "Umeå X",
    "sub-title": "Brandning and webdesign",
    "link": "brixtar.html",
    "CTA": "Read more"}],

"case-study-racefox":[{
    "img": "../assets/img/racefox-1.jpg",
    "title": "Racefox Run",
    "sub-title": "Brandning app design",
    "link": "brixtar.html",
    "CTA": "Read more"}],

"case-study-interflora":[{
    "img": "../assets/img/caseIF.jpg",
    "title": "Interflora",
    "sub-title": "Webdesign",
    "link": "brixtar.html",
    "CTA": "Read more"}]
  };
  
  Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEqualsChained', function() {
      var options = arguments[arguments.length-1];
      // Assuming that all wanted operator are '||'
      valueToTest=arguments[0];
      for (var i = 1; i < (arguments.length - 1); i++) {
        if (valueToTest === arguments[i]) {
          return options.fn(this);
        }
      }
      return options.inverse(this);
  });
  var source = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#*inline "img-bg"}}
background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
{{/inline}}
{{#each case-study-pk}}
<div class="grid-x">
  <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 img-double-height foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
    {{> img-bg}}">
    <div class="top-left down">
      <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
      <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}

<div class="cell small-12 medium-4">
    <div class="grid-y tile-y-bg-double-height">
      {{#each work.case-study-brixtar}}
      <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6 tile2 aligner-left foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
        {{> img-bg}}">
        <div class="align-self-bottom down tile-padding ">
          <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
          <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}} 
      
      {{#each work.case-study-memontus}}
      <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6 tile2 aligner-left foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
        {{> img-bg}}">
        <div class="align-self-bottom down tile-padding ">
          <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
          <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid-container full">

  <div class="grid-x align-center-middle text-center">

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4">
      {{#each work.case-study-umeax}}
      <div class="grid-y tile-y-bg-single-height">
        <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-12 tile4 aligner-left foo" style="background-image: url({{img}});
          {{> img-bg}}">
          <div class="align-self-bottom down tile-padding">
            <h3 class="left-align mb-zero text-shadow"><a href={{link}} class="white-link">{{title}}</a></h3>
            <h5 class="left-align upper-case text-shadow">{{sub-title}}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-8 img-single-height aligner cell-text-padder">
      <h3 class="medium p-white ">Floe is the world’s greatest design agency, apart from a few others. But the few others eat million dollar budgets for breakfast – we eat porridge!</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</script>

<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```